# Remove a line with specific characters in a variable before putting into CSV

Tags: php

I would like to ask what is the efficient way to achieve this.

I have a variable that holds the data below which is to be pass into a CSV file.

```
"Name","Address","Email","Comment"
", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, "
"John Smith","USA","john@john.net","No Comment"
```

What I want to achieve is to remove the second line so that before I push the data into the CSV those characters already remove.

```
", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, "
```

The only thing that I can do right now is to save the data into a file then manipulate it then use it for CSV but I am sure there is a faster way to manipulate.

Comment: @Dagon, can you give example? I can replace a string to empty but I cannot remove the whole line. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line always looks like that?  As Dagon suggested:

```
$yourdata = str_replace('", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, ",", <=, "', '', $yourdata);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

If that junk data is always every other line, it would be much more efficient just to skip it as you re-build your data into a variable, reading line-by-line.

Comment: Thank you Brad, your sample helps a lot. I also add  preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $yourdata); to remove empty line.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a small filter to automatically discard those lines as they are encountered.  Something simple like:

```
function filtered_fputcsv($fp, $fields) {
  if ($fields ...has relevant data...) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
  }
}
```

and use this in place of the standard writer (or a similar version for reading).